# How to fetch the value in input hidden field through li data-val

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to the selcted data-id value to be fetch in input hidden field

Here is my source code:

```js
jQuery('li').click(function() {
  $('#car').html(jQuery(this).attr("data-val"));
}); <
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-val="all">Allahabad</li>
  <li data-val="pra">Pratapgarh</li>
  <li data-val="kan">kanpur</li>
  <li data-val="chd">Chandigarh</li>
  <li data-val="ldh">Ludhiana</li>
</ul>

<input type="text" name="car" id="car" value=" ">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this,html function is used for setting the html content for setting the values use val() function

```
 $('#car').val(jQuery(this).attr("data-val"));
```

Answer (score 6):

.html() will set the html contents for elements(which is invalid for input elements). You need to set value and not html. use `.val()`:

```
 $('#car').val($(this).attr("data-val"));
```